# Send order to different dropshippers by product

Tags: magento2, email, order-email

A customer of mine is going to work with a few different dropshippers. It's going to be a Magento 2 Webshop.

What they want is: if a visitor orders Product A, an email should be send to the dropshippers that delivers product A. And if Product B is ordered, Magento should send an email to the other dropshipper that delivers Product B.

So the main question is: Can new order e-mails be send to different email addresses by choice of product?

Answer (score 0):

No this isnt standard functionality as magento is not multi vendor by default, this is something you would either make youself or have made by another developer. i made similar functionality in m1